# Avoid if __name__ == '__main__' in Python subclasses to be run using function from parent

Tags: python, subclass

I have a generic class (A) which is to be subclassed a lot like this:

```
class A:
    def run(self):
        ...
        self.do_something()
        ...

    #abstract function
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def do_something(self):
        ...
```

The subclasses are in separate files that I'm running directly by adding this code to each file (B is the name of the subclass in the file):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    B().run()
```

My question is, can I avoid having to add this code to all files with the subclasses since the only thing that changes in the code is the class being used (B in the example)?

Comment: BTW you can use `@abc.abstractmethod` to enforce the requirement that `do_something` _actually_ be abstract.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I actually use it, just didn't want to make the example more complex than needed... But tks anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your python version is recent enough, you can create a class decorator.

In this case, an indirect one.

```
def runifmain(mainname):
    def deco(clas):
        if mainname == '__main__':
            clas().run()
        return clas
    return deco


@runifmain(__name__)
class B(A):
    [...]
```

should do the job if you define `runifmain()` somewhere centrally and just use the `@runifmain(__name__)`wherever it is needed.

Comment: Very interesting, I had used decorators before but didn't think they were this easy to use. Still, unless there is a way to put the decorator in class A I'll still have to add the import plus the decorator in each subclass file which doesn't sound much simpler then what I had before. This still deserves an upvote which I'd give you if my reputation was high enough! xD

Comment: I have enough reputation now, there's your up vote! Tks again!

Comment: thx :-) But you only need to put the decorator in one file and can import it into the single files. There should even be a way to put it into the class definition itself, if you decorate it with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: I know I don't need the definition of the decorator everywhere, I'm talking about the decorator itself. An import plus a decorator equals two extra lines per file, the same as I had before!
Still, I decided to use it if only because it looks cooler! =D

Comment: If it is in the same module, you need no extra import - just use it as `@module.runifmain(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

What about adding an extra function to your main class A?

```
class A():
    ..
    def __RunIfMain__(self,name):
        if name == '__main__':
            self.run()
```

In your subclass you'd have one line less:

```
class B(A):
  ..

B().__RunIfMain__(__name__)
```

Comment: Well, you got me with one line less, that's for sure, but the decorator from glglgl's answer looked sexier... xD
Tks anyway!